# How can I show that $ P = \dfrac{vv^T}{v\cdot v}$ is a projection matrix for non-zero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $v$ be in $R^n$ be a non zero vector. How do I show that $ P = 
\dfrac{vv^T}{v\cdot v}$ is a projection matrix? Looking for some help  (the denominator is dotted together but didn't know the formatting)

Comment: If you have similar Questions, bear in mind that such short phrasing leaves most Readers in doubt where your difficulty lies.  Is it in finding a definition for "projection matrix"?  Is it in the matter of checking a specific aspect of that definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a projection matrix is an idempotent one. That is, we are to show $PP=P$. This follows because
$$
PP=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)^2}vv^Tvv^T=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)^2}v(v^Tv)v^T=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)^2}v(v\cdot v)v^T=\frac{1}{(v\cdot v)}vv^T=P.
$$
In addition, you can also check that $P$ is symmetric so $P$ is in fact an orthogonal projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can proove that $P^2 = P$.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy for getting started in this sort of questions would always be similar:

> write down the **definition** of projection matrices and check that $P$ satisfies the definition.

Where did you get stuck?